# How to build libvirt-go for windows on mac

Tags: libvirt

I installed the libs and can run/debug the  libvirt related codes in idea IDE,  but after running below build command on MacBook

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -o zagent.exe cmd/test/main.go
```

I got

```
cmd/test/main.go:11:22: undefined: libvirt.NewConnect
```

Thank you for your attention, below is the codes:

```
package main

import (
    _logUtils "github.com/easysoft/zagent/internal/pkg/lib/log"
    "github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go"
)

func main() {
    connStr := "***"

    LibvirtConn, err := libvirt.NewConnect(connStr)
    if err != nil {
        _logUtils.Errorf(err.Error())
        return
    }

    active, err := LibvirtConn.IsAlive()
    if err != nil {
        _logUtils.Errorf(err.Error())
        return
    }
    if !active {
        _logUtils.Errorf("not active")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libvirt-go package is a CGo based API to the underlying libvirt.so library. You cannot set CGO_ENABLED=0 and expect it to still work. AFAI, Go toolchain doesn't allow cross-compiling with CGo either.

Comment: So how can I exclude virtlib related files when I build a client app without virtlib support?

Comment: You'll have to use a go build tag in any of your source files that are using libvirt to let them be disabled in some way